# Full list of Jquery keyboard character codes on keypress()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know that 13 symbolizes `ENTER` . But I want to know which number is for A, B, C.. etc.. Does anyone know where I can find a full of list keyboard buttons for jquery keypress.

```
$(document).keypress(function (e) {
      if (e.which == 13) {
             $(".car").css("left", "+=25px");
      }
});
```

Comment: Hi, please remember to always Google first. Thanks!

Comment: This question is better than the comments suggest. It is asking for key codes, not character codes, and the naive answers suggesting a look at ASCII code (whatever that might mean) are just wrong and show that the question is useful.

Comment: @Jukka either way, the answer is trivial to find. Just because some people suggest ASCII tables it doesn't mean the question adds any value. The only useful thing here is Anton's answer

Comment: It might be trivial to find, but then the constructive approach is to mark it as a duplicate (and perhaps improve the answers to an old question).

Comment: @Jukka that's not a realistic goal for the 7,000 new questions SO gets every day, many of which are of this caliber. The fact that the OP is exceptionally rude doesn't increase the motivation either. People need to invest 30 seconds of homework before asking a question, period. If we can't expect even that, this place is lost.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Many people found (and probably will) find this question useful, contrary to your own belief. I googled about this subject but didn't find much, however, I LEARNED A LOT AFTER I ASKED THIS QUESTION. By the way, maybe you don't know, but no-one is putting a gun to your head to stay in this topic.

Comment: The answer gets +3 and the question gets -3! WHY? :)

Comment: Upped 1. I don't know why this is downvoted. jQuerys `keypress` uses different keycodes than `keyup` or the standard JavaScript keycodes. I'd like a full list as well.

Comment: @Pekka웃, you do realize that some of us get this page as one of our first Google results, right?

Comment: @Max yes, these questions often tend to. All the more reason to nuke them really.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

A simple way of of checking out keycodes yourself you could do it like this:

```js
$('input').on('keydown', function (e) {
    $('label').text(e.keyCode);
});
```

#### [Demo in JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmmz8/)

Also, take a look at this [page on Javascript Char Codes (Key Codes)](https://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes)

Comment: If you are using jqueryui, the keycodes are already mapped to easily readable labels:
http://api.jqueryui.com/jQuery.ui.keyCode/